# Help with single left label for multiple items with a single left brace

Tags: itemize, labels

I have a list in the `itemize` environment and I would like to have it all grouped with a left curly brace that points to a symbol like `(*)` that works as a label that I can reference later. Currently, my code looks like this:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\begin{document}

$(*)\left\{
\begin{tabular}{p{.8\textwidth}}
\begin{itemize}
\item Second line 
\item Third line, which is quite long and seemingly tedious in the extreme
\item Fourth line, which isn't as long as the third 
\end{itemize}
\end{tabular}
\right.$
\end{document}
```

However, this isn't ideal because I can't get `\label{(*)}` or something similar to work, so I can't use `\ref` on it later. If someone could help me with this it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Could you please make your example compilable by adding the documentclass as well as teh relevant packages? What output would you expect from the `\ref` command in that case?

Comment: @leandriis Sorry about that, just edited it. What I'm hoping for is that the reader can click on the output of \ref and be taken back to the label. Your other answer gave me exactly what I'm looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of `\hypertarget` and `\hyperlink` from the `hyperref` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\hypertarget{mylabel}{\[(*)\left\lbrace
\begin{tabular}{p{.8\textwidth}}
\begin{itemize}
\item Second line 
\item Third line, which is quite long and seemingly tedious in the extreme
\item Fourth line, which isn't as long as the third 
\end{itemize}
\end{tabular}
\right.\]}
This is some text with a ref to \hyperlink{mylabel}{(*)}

\end{document}
```

I'd suggest to also load the `enumitem` package in order to improve the spacing around the `itemize` environment, for example as follows:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newlist{tabitem}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[tabitem]{label=\textbullet,leftmargin=*, nosep,leftmargin=*,before=\vspace{-0.5\baselineskip},after=\vspace{-1\baselineskip}}

\begin{document}

\hypertarget{mylabel}{\[(*)\left\lbrace
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{.8\textwidth}}
\begin{tabitem}
\item Second line 
\item Third line, which is quite long and seemingly tedious in the extreme
\item Fourth line, which isn't as long as the third 
\end{tabitem}
\end{tabular}
\right.\]}
This is some text with a ref to \hyperlink{mylabel}{(*)}

\end{document}
```